# How to select the dictionary that minimizes a key along a set of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, minimize

I have two(n) Python dictionaries `dict_1 = {"obj_value": 1, "other_key": 10}` and `dict_2 = {"obj_value": 0, "other_key": 10}` and I need a rutine that returns the dictionary that minimizes the `obj_value` key, in this case, `dict_2`

Any ideas about this problem without using conditionals (if)? I would want to extend this to more than two dictionaries.

Comment: If you're planning to extend this to a larger number of dictionaries: what does that extension look like? If you provide a concrete example you are likely to get better responses to your question

Comment: Do you have list of dictionaries

Comment: Actually I am not that interested in the extension of the container of my dictionaries, so it could be an array, a list, other dictionary, or whatever. The number of dictionaries is not huge, maybe up to 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min`

```
min(dict1, dict2,.., key=lambda x : x.get("obj_value"))
```

Also if there are list of dictionaries then
l_o_d = [{dict}]
Then
You can use

```
min(*l_o_d, key=lambda x : x.get("obj_value"))
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For the case of two dictionaries as you have it, a conditional is good enough:

```
chosen_dict = dict_1 if dict_1["object_value"] < dict_2["object_value"] else dict_2
```

For the general case, it depends a bit on the data structure you are using. Let's assume a simple extension with a list of dictionaries, like:

```
all_dictionaries = [
    {"obj_value": 1, "other_key": 10},
    {"obj_value": 0, "other_key": 10},
    {"obj_value": 2, "other_key": 10},
    ...
    {"obj_value": 999, "other_key": 10},
]
```

In this case you can simply sort the list by the key, like so:

```
chosen_dict = sorted(all_dictionaries, key=lambda x: x["obj_value"])[0]
```

This sorts the list by the `key` attribute, with this picking out the value for the `obj_value` in each dictionary, then we simply take the 0th element, which is a dictionary with the lowest value for the `object_value` key.

You can do something similar with `min`:

```
chosen_dict = min(all_dictionaries, key=lambda x: x["obj_value"])
```

Comment: Sorting is overkill when you are only looking for the minimum value within a list.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it is very helpful. I think i will use the `min` solution instead of the `sorted` one